# Spring REST Docs - WS02 integration

Tags: spring-restdocs

I have been looking at Spring REST doc and have been suitably impressed. However organisational constraints require that all developed REST API's must be registered in the WS02 registry. 
I had a brief look at the WS02 registry and it allows for a Swagger YAML file. Is there anyway that Spring REST docs can be leveraged to allow integration with WS02 or has any consideration been given to this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below github project. A few teams at my company are using this to generate Swagger specs for WSO2 from Spring Rest Docs.

https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-api-spec